# Uitableview getting Async Data from Internet, Screen is Blank until timeout or data available

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to let the User Know that the App is loading Data, so I tried everything.

I just added a new view named LoadingData and putted this in my Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    


LoadingData *loadingDataView = [[LoadingData alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingData" bundle:nil];

[window addSubview:[loadingDataView view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];



Connection *connection = [[Connection alloc] init];
[connection getUserDefaults];



[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

That means I want the view to show until Connection with the Async request is finished.....

I just tried everything please help.
But everytime the Async request blocks everything in the View

But i still see the Blank Page at first and no

---

@albertamg

This is my connection method:

```
-(BOOL) connectAsync
{

    // ==== BEGIN DEBUGGING OUTPUT
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                self.url];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:20];

    NSLog(@"request :  %@", request);
    // [request setValue:agentString forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    NSError        *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse  *response = nil;


    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


    NSLog(@"Connection Error:      %@", error);
    //NSLog(@"Code:   %@", [error code]);
    NSLog(@"UserInfo: %@", [error userInfo]);
    NSLog(@"Domain: %@",  [error domain]);

    NSLog(@"HelpAnchor: %@", [error helpAnchor]);

    NSLog(@"Connection Response: %@", response);


    if(error !=nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {

        NSString *returnData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"returnData:  %@", returnData); 
        // === END DEBUGGING OUTPUT
        return YES;

    }

}
```

I will try to use Threads as next step, thx to JAson Cragun, I`ll post asap if it worked or not....

---

So i still have a Problem on this....

Here is my Code for the Appdelegate, I first start an Loading Data view and start another view as soon the Thread finishes.....

But still the blank Page, why the hell its still not working with the Thread?
I know my code isnt the nicest but I just want to test it first:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    


LoadingData *loadingDataView = [[LoadingData alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingData" bundle:nil];

[window addSubview:[loadingDataView view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

Connection *connection = [[Connection alloc] init];
[connection getUserDefaults];



NSThread *connectThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:(connection) selector:@selector(connectAsyncThread) object:nil];


[connectThread start]; 

while ([connectThread isExecuting]) 
{
    NSLog(@"WAit for Thread.....");
}

if (![connectThread isExecuting]) {
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];


    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

}

Comment: can you show the code of your Connection class?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you need to add more details, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5822307/edit).  Answers are supposed to be answers, not additional information about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your connection class is not async (although you think it is)...

You are creating the loading view on the main UI thread which will not update the UI until the connection code has completed.

you should spin off a new thread to do the busy work.

[NSThread  detachNewThreadSelector...]

(void)detachNewThreadSelector:(SEL)selector toTarget:(id)target withObject:(id)argument;

which is where you will create your new connection object and perform the lengthy work. Dont forget to create an NSAutoreleasePool in that thread.

here is a reference

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your help, I did edit my post you will see that I still have Problems....

Answer (score 1):

Ok,.. in response to the next part of the question... we are having issues updating the main UI AFTER the thread has completed.. here is a better approach using Grand Central Dispatch.  GCD gives us the plumbing for threads without the complexity.. it also gives us access to variables across the different threads..

this example spins off a background thread.. then when its done, it fires a block of code on the main thread, which is where we need to update the UI

```
 dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    dispatch_async(q, ^
                   {
                       //do background work here

                       dispatch_sync(main, ^
                                     {


                                         // update UI here


                                     });


                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ASIHTTPRequest for your web client work, and DEFINITELY should be using the asynchronous methods for that.

It's as easy as:

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *r = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithUrl:myNSURLObject];
[r setCompletionBlock:^{
    //do whatever to process your received data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
[r startAsynchronous];
```